# meteor http post to other domain

Tags: javascript, http, post, meteor

So I want to use an sms service from 46elks in my meteor project. The following php script allows you to send an sms:

```
<?
// Example to send SMS using the 46elks service
// Change $username, $password and the mobile number to send to

function sendSMS ($sms) {

  // Set your 46elks API username and API password here
  // You can find them at https://dashboard.46elks.com/
  $username = 'u2c11ef65b429a8e16ccb1f960d02c734';
  $password = 'C0ACCEEC0FAFE879189DD5D57F6EC348';

  $context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'header'  => "Authorization: Basic ".
                   base64_encode($username.':'.$password). "\r\n".
                   "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
      'content' => http_build_query($sms),
      'timeout' => 10
  )));

  return false !== file_get_contents(
    'https://api.46elks.com/a1/SMS', false, $context );
}


$sms = array(
  'from' => 'DummyFrom',   /* Can be up to 11 alphanumeric characters */
  'to' => '+46400000000',  /* The mobile number you want to send to */
  'message' => 'Hello hello!'
);
sendSMS ($sms);

?>
```

Now I need this in my meteor project and I've been trying to convert it to meteors http.call():

```
HTTP.call("POST", "https://api.46elks.com/a1/SMS", {
                headers:
                {
                    "Authorization": "Basic SomeLongBase46EncodedString",
                    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },

                data:
                {
                    "from": "testFrom",
                    "to": "+46701111111",
                    "message": "test message"
                }
            },

            function (error, result)
            {
                if (error)
                {
                    console.log("error: " + error);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("result: " + result);
                }
            });
```

But what I keep getting is the following error:

`error: Error: failed [403] Missing key from`

Comment: If it's a 403 then it sounds like an authentication issue.  Does your authorization string look okay and are you encoding it correctly?

Comment: I have tried encoding the `username + ":" + password` with two different methods and both gave identical strings so it should not be a problem there. I would guess form the message that the "from" field is not being posted correctly?

Comment: One comment: Would better hide user and password strings for security reason.

Comment: Thank you but they are fake values

Answer (score 5):

Change `data` to `params`:

```
params: {
      "from": "testFrom",
      "to": "+46701111111",
      "message": "test message"
}
```

and use `auth` instead of `Authorization` ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#http_call)):

```
"auth": username + ":" + password
```

Answer (score 2):

ok, I had to replace `data: { ... }` with the following formatted string:

```
content: "from=testFrom&to=+46701111111&message=test message"
```

This to convert the php http_build_query() correctly.